# Doctrine findBy() repeat n times the same row

Tags: php, oracle, symfony, doctrine

I've been working with symfony and doctrine the last year and have encountered nothing like this.

So I have a simple oracle table and a doctrine entity with an id, 3 varchars and without relationships. No repository either:

```
[Configuracion]  id  |  nombre  |  descripcion  |  valor
                 1     'rgpd'     'Codigos rgps'    '2p'
                 2     'motivo' 'Motivos de visita' '2p'
                ...      ...            ...         ...
```

I can persist() and find() with no problem.
When doing the search:

> $result = $entityManager->getRepository(Configuracion::class)->findBy(array('valor'=>'2p'))

and then dump($result) I get the same row repeated:

```
[Configuracion]  id  |  nombre  |  descripcion  |  valor
                 1     'rgpd'     'Codigos rgps'    '2p'
                 1     'rgpd'     'Codigos rgps'    '2p'
                ...      ...            ...         ...
```

If I add five diferents elements to the database the result becomes five times the same row. If I deleted this row It just takes the next one to clone. 
I know I could try with QueryBuilder or NativeQuery instead, but I want to know why doctrine is doing this.

Comment: Doctrine should not de doing this and would not be doing this using mysql as db (I am pretty sure about that), so I suppose its an issue with oracle db in combination with doctrine, or you have to configure doctrine so it knows you are using oracle db (or oracle db needs a special configuration)..., but I know that you have to tell doctrine that you are using mariadb and not mysql in order to expect the same behavior, so I think this could be a solution

Comment: I have others entities working but this one seems corrupted.I tried deleting the entity and re-make it but nothing. I don't think the oracle driver is the issue and the unit of work in doctrine is empty prior to the select so that can't be. Maybe is the table that has something strange from creation. I can't drop it and create it again so I'll stick to QueryBuilder

Comment: I am not quite familiar with how oracle db works,... but does your table has a unique key index? I wouldn't surprise me if doctrine uses the primary key of a table in order to defer the single entries